# How check an empty array in the observable?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have trouble with rxJava for android. I spend a lot of time to solve my issue, about one day, but can't find the answer. About my question. I have a query to database and I want to check an empty array and I show a message about that in the subscriber. Yes I can do that, but I think there is a better solution. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206735/fallback-observable-for-rxjava) I found similar question but this operator doesn't work for me. 
Here is my code of observable and subscriber

```
private void getCategory(){
    observable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<PaginatedScanList<ProductDO>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super PaginatedScanList<ProductDO>> subscriber) {
            final Map<String, AttributeValue> filterExpressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
            filterExpressionAttributeValues
                    .put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS(category));
            final DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
                    .withFilterExpression("category = :val1")
                    .withExpressionAttributeValues(filterExpressionAttributeValues);
            PaginatedScanList<ProductDO> result = dynamoDBMapper.scan(ProductDO.class, scanExpression);
            Log.d(TAG, "response size is " + result.size());
            subscriber.onNext(result);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    }).switchIfEmpty(Observable.create(subscriber -> subscriber.onNext(null)));
    subscriber = new Subscriber<ProductDO>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            loadCategoryProduct.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "something went wrong, please restart app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(ProductDO productDO) {
            if (productDO == null)
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No item in this category", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {
                productItem.add(productDO);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d(TAG, "result category " + productDO.getName());
            }
        }
    };
    observable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap(product -> Observable.from(product))
            .subscribe(subscriber);
}
```

Please help me, I don't know why switchIfEmpty doesn't work or maybe I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `filter` operator instead of `switchIfEmpty`

```
.filter(result -> {
    if(result.size() > 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        //Show your toast here
        return false;
    }
})
```

`switchIfEmpty` doesn't work in the way you proposed. It doesn't have any information about the item being a list or how to get a size of it. The word 'empty' in the operator's name represents an empty stream, meaning that it would emit items from backup observable ( your null emission )  only when there were no emissions and onComplete call from the original stream, not when the emitted list was empty.

Comment: Ouh, thanks, it's help me) Are you know why my solution not work?

Comment: I edited my answer to better explain why your solution didn't work. If you have solved the problem, please mark the answer as accepted so others know you no longer need assistance

Comment: It is not a good idea to pollute `filter` body with unrelated actions (toast). Consider using `doOnNext` before `filter` to check if result is empty and show toast if so.